# How to assign unknown number of variables

Tags: bash

Given the following command

```
set -- $(multipath -ll 36000d310004014000000000000000165 |grep 'sd' |awk '{print $3}')
```

which, for example, provides the following output in once case:

```
sdv
sdvx
```

and in another might be

```
sdik
sdim
sdx
```

how can I grab the output eg. $1, $2, etc when I don't know how many values will be returned ahead of time? I could end up with two, three, maybe four paths that I want to work with.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a for loop:

```
( set -- $(multipath -ll 36000d310004014000000000000000165 | awk '/sd/{print $3}');
for arg; do echo "$arg"; done; )
```

Few suggested improvements:

- Avoid `grep` as `awk` can also search in a line
- Better to use a subshell to avoid overriding positional variables in current shell
- Use a `for arg; do ... done` construct to loop through all positional arguments

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a while loop and shift the args thru (built on @anubhava's answer):

```
( set -- $(multipath -ll 36000d310004014000000000000000165 | awk '/sd/{print $3}');
while [ ! -z "$1" ] ; do echo "$1"; shift; done; )
```